# Radio buttons for 3 boolean properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model with 3 properties:

```
public class OptionsViewModel {
  public Boolean A { get; set; }
  public Boolean B { get; set; }
  public Boolean C { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display 3 radio buttons for the 3 properties included the same group.

So I added the following

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.A)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.B)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.C)
```

I do have thee Boolean properties and not just one ...

The code does not compile because RadioButtonFor does not have such a constructor.

I tried a few variations but I end up being able to select many radio buttons or the binding does not work ...

Could someone tell me the best way to solve this with the model I have?

Comment: A radio button group only posts back one value. If you want to post back values for each of the 3 properties, use `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` or create a radio button group (true/false) for each property

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.A, "A", true) A
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.B, "B", true) B
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.C, "C", false) C
```

More here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/how-to-create-radio-button-in-asp-net-mvc3-razor-application/

Comment: I don't get it ... Why specifying the Boolean value? I want the boolean value to be taken of each model property ...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to display 3 radio buttons for the 3 properties included the same group.

You'll have to update your model:

```
public class OptionsViewModel {
  public bool A { get; set; }
  public bool B { get; set; }
  public bool C { get; set; }
  public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then your razor:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Value, "A", model.A) A
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Value, "B", model.B) B
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Value, "C", model.C) C
```

With a RadioButton you only get 1 value back.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me:

Razor code:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.A, "A", new { @Name = "sign", @checked = Model.A })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.B, "B", new { @Name = "sign", @checked = Model.B })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.C, "C", new { @Name = "sign", @checked = Model.C })
```

Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Add(ModelType dataItem, FormCollection formValues)
{
   dataItem.A = formValues["sign"] == "A";
   dataItem.B = formValues["sign"] == "B";
   dataItem.C = formValues["sign"] == "C";
   ...
}
```